# ftpPublish declarative pipeline

Tags: node.js, jenkins, groovy, ftp, jenkins-pipeline

I have the following pipeline:

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    stages {
        ... building stuff...
        stage('push to develop'){
            when {
                branch 'develop' 
            }
            steps {
                ftpPublisher paramPublish: [ parameterName: "" ], alwaysPublishFromMaster: true, masterNodeName: master, continueOnError: false, failOnError: false, publishers: [
                    [configName: 'cp-front', usePromotionTimestamp: false, useWorkspaceInPromotion: false, verbose: true, transfers: [
                        [asciiMode: false, cleanRemote: false, excludes: '', flatten: false, makeEmptyDirs: false, noDefaultExcludes: false, patternSeparator: '[, ]+', remoteDirectorySDF: false, removePrefix: '', sourceFiles: '**/*']
                    ]]
                ]
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, this throws:

> groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: master for
>   class: groovy.lang.Binding    at
>   groovy.lang.Binding.getVariable(Binding.java:63)  at
>   org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.groovy.SandboxInterceptor.onGetProperty(SandboxInterceptor.java:264)
>     at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker$6.call(Checker.java:288)
>     at
>   org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker.checkedGetProperty(Checker.java:292)
>     at
>   org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker.checkedGetProperty(Checker.java:268)
>     at
>   org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker.checkedGetProperty(Checker.java:268)
>     at
>   com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.sandbox.SandboxInvoker.getProperty(SandboxInvoker.java:29)
>     at
>   com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.PropertyAccessBlock.rawGet(PropertyAccessBlock.java:20)
>     at WorkflowScript.run(WorkflowScript:22)

Which gives me about 0 idea what is going on. Any pointers?

Comment: Shouldn't it be: `masterNodeName: 'master'`?

Comment: sigh. there go 3 hours of my life. if you are willing to convert that to an answer I will accept it. thanks

Comment: Done. It happens sometimes - no worries ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`master` (an object, property) is not equal to `'master'` - which is an instance of `String`. Maybe you made a simple mistake?